# NetBeans: How to enable/disable specific tab in JTabedPane

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtabbedpane

I am developing a small desktop application in Netbeans. on my UI i have a `JTabbedPane` having 3 tabs in it now i come across a situation where i need to temporarily disable 2nd and 3rd tab. How could i do that programatically. Rightnow i am using the following code but its not working:

```
int n = jTabbedPane1.indexOfTab("Second Tab Name");// This line returns one as expected
jTabbedPane1.getTabComponentAt(n).enable(false);// but i guess some un-expected thing happens here
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is this.

```
jTabbedPane1.setEnabledAt(n, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use

```
 tabObject.setEnabledAt(index, enabled);
```

tabObject :- is the JTabbedPane
index would start from 0.So,you Should use 1 and 2 for the second and third tabs
enabled is the Boolean value true for on and false for off.
   i think it helps